# Only the last object in the array populating with a NSMutableArray list

Tags: objective-c

I have created an NSMutableArray; when I run the simulator, it only populates the last item's object name in the cells.  Why is this?

I believe the issue as at the very bottom as to why it may not be populating properly.

```
@interface WineListTableViewController ()
@end    
@implementation WineListTableViewController    
@synthesize currentVarietal;    

NSMutableArray *list;

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    DescriptionWineViewController *dvc= [segue destinationViewController];
    [dvc setCurrentVarietal: [self currentVarietal]];

}


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    wine *varietal =[[wine alloc] init];

    [varietal setName:@"Barbera"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Barbera's Flavor Profile:\n..."];
    [list addObject:varietal];


    [varietal setName:@"Chenin Blanc"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Chenin Blanc's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Lambrusco"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Lambrusco's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Malbec"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Malbec's Flavor Profile:\n ..."];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Merlot"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Merlot's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Montepulciano"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Montepulciano's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Muscat"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Muscat's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Nebbiolo"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Nebbiolo's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Petite Syrah"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Petite Syrah's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Pinot Gris"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Pinot Gris's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Pinot Grigio"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Pinot Grigio's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Pinot Noir"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Pinot Noir's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Sangiovese"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Sangiovese's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Shiraz/ Syrah"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Shiraz/ Syrah's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Viognier"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Viognier's Flavor Profile:\n ..."];
    [list addObject:varietal];

    [varietal setName:@"Zinfandel"];
    [varietal setNotes:@"Zinfandel's Flavor Profile:\n ..."];
    [list addObject:varietal];



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [list count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell ==nil){
        cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

    //this is the code I think must be incorrect

    wine *current= [list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[current name]];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You keep adding the same object again and again.  Use ***different*** objects.

Comment: (Hint: `[[wine alloc] init]` creates an object.)

Comment: (Find a good text on object-oriented programming and study it.)

Comment: Ha!  Thanks.  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Note that class names are capitalized;  that should be `Wine`, not `wine`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same object.
Use `varietal =[[wine alloc] init];` after every `addObject` to create different ones.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have one object (`varietal`) that you mutate (meaning you change its properties). 

*So you really only add one object to the array.*

To fix this, **release** `varietal` after you add it to the array (the array retains it) and **create a new object** to be added:

```
wine *varietal =[[wine alloc] init];
[varietal setName:@"Barbera"];
[varietal setNotes:@"Barbera's Flavor Profile:\n..."];
[list addObject:varietal];
[varietal release]; // Remove this line under ARC (Auto Reference Counting)

wine *varietal =[[wine alloc] init];
[varietal setName:@"Chenin Blanc"];
[varietal setNotes:@"Chenin Blanc's Flavor Profile:\n... "];
[list addObject:varietal];
[varietal release]; // Remove this line under ARC (Auto Reference Counting)

wine *varietal =[[wine alloc] init];
// etc…
```

**Note:** *If you are using ARC (the default for all new projects under the current Xcode version), you do not need to call `[varietal release];`. It will even produce an error. If you don't use  ARC, not releasing `varietal` will result in a memory leak.*